# How to model entities to enforce a data models constraints at compile time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, enums

I have the below data model that constrains *ItemTypes* with a subset of *Events*.  Each *ItemType* has a valid set of *Events*, this is constrained in the ItemEvent table.  For example, a Video can be { played, stopped, paused }, an Image can be { resized, saved, or shared }, and so on.

[image]

What is the best way to reflect this constraint in the Entity model so that I can get compile time assurance that an Event used is valid for a particular Item? Specifically, I am refactoring the AddItemEventLog method:

```
public void AddItemEventLog(Item item, string ItemEvent)
{
    //
}
```

Obviously, this is a contrived example, just trying illustrate-- it allows a developer to pass in any ItemEvent string they desire.  Even if I create an enumeration based on ItemEvent resultset, there isnt anything in the entity model to prevent a developer from passing in *ItemEvent.Resize* with an Item of type *Video*.

I have Item as the base class of Video, and I have tried to override an enum but now know that is not possible.  I am less interested in checking for the validity of the Event at runtime, as I already will throw an exception when the DB raises a FK violation. I want to nip it in the bud at coding time if possible :)

Currently have classes modeled like this but open to any modifications:

```
 //enums.cs
 public enum ItemType : byte
 {
     Video = 1,
     Image = 2,
     Document = 3
 }

 //item.cs
 public class Item : BaseModel
 {
     public int ItemId { get; set; }
     public ItemTypeLookup.ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
     public string ItemName { get; set; }
 }

//video.cs
public class Video : Item
{
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Thumb { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: No, not using Entity Framework

Comment: Are you writing one model class per table?

Comment: I added some class detail to answer questions.  I am open to any refactoring advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) may be the only way to enforce something like this at compile time. Outside of compile time checks, writing unit tests to ensure the correct functionality is the next best thing!